# Node server in docker container runs and updates but will not load in browser

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04, wsl-2

This was previously working fine:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

ARG NODE_ENV
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ]; \
        then npm install; \
        else npm install --only=production; \
        fi

COPY . ./
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE $PORT
# For development
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
# For production
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

---

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx: 
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports: 
      - "3000:80"
    volumes: 
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
  node-app: 
    build: .
    environment: 
      - PORT=3000 
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
  mongo: 
    image: mongo
    environment: 
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=password
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=username
    volumes: 
      - mongo-db:/data/db
  redis:
    image: redis
      
volumes: 
  mongo-db:
```

---

docker-compose.dev.yml:

```
version: "3"
services: 
  nginx: 
    ports: 
      - "3000:80"
  node-app:
    build: 
      context: .
      args: 
        NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - ./:/app:ro
      - /app/node_modules
    environment: 
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - MONGO_USER=username
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=password
      - SESSION_SECRET=secret
    command: npm run dev
  mongo: 
    environment: 
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=username
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

node server:

```
#
#
#
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));
```

I am using the container's ip address just as always

ran $ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN

it shows no apps listening on any ports except for the following:

tcp6       0      0 :::35987                :::*                    LISTEN      28/node

App and container are running inside of a WSL2 Ubuntu VM inside a Windows 10 machine

Running netstat inside of the running container's bash yields the following:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:39311        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -

Comment: I have a hunch that this is a WSL2/Windows problem

Comment: What's your WSL distros? Go to Powershell(open as Admin) and Run this command: `wsl -l -v` . what's the output ?

Comment: also what's the content of `./nginx/default.conf` ?

Comment: also how are you trying to access it on the browser ? http://localhost:3000 for example ?